# Solving A Race Condition When Using find_or_create_by

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, race-condition

I am using

```
@current_device ||= Device.find_or_create_by!(udid: request.headers["udid"])
```

and sometimes there is a race condition, where due to network behavior, 2 requests come at the same time, which causes 2 devices to be created with the same udid, even though there is a validation on the udid column for uniqueness.

I tried to engulf this with

```
begin
    @current_device ||= Device.find_or_create_by!(udid: request.headers["udid"])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
            if e.message == 'Validation failed: Udid has already been taken'
                retry #to compensate/handle possible(and very happening) race condition
             else
                Rollbar.error(e)
             end
end
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a better way to handle this race condition?

Comment: Lock the table first. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670

Comment: Never depend on ActiveRecord validations to ensure uniqueness, add a unique constraint inside the database and handle the exception in Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort but won't that still cause a race condition?

Comment: You can have races if multiple connections are trying to update the same `Device` but the unique constraint inside the database will prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

https://rietta.com/blog/2015/05/04/validates-uniqueness-race-condition-in-ruby-on-rails/

Fix race condition at the database level